# What aspects should I test from a fitted GARCH model?

Tags: python, residuals, heteroscedasticity, garch, diagnostic

I estimated a GARCH(1,1) assuming that the residuals follow Student-$t$ distribution.

```
garch = arch_model(Y, X, mean="LS", vol="GARCH", p=1, q=1, dist="t")
```

Now I can't get what aspects should I check. I need standardized residuals or residuals? What test should I use and how many lags? (Number of observation is 1039.)

Comment: Here is an academic paper about this: Lundbergh & Teräsvirta ["Evaluating GARCH models"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407602000969) (2002).

Comment: @RichardHardy I can not find any information about how to do li-mak test in python. I am using arch_model library. Sorry to bother you. thank you again

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Python. You may consider calling R from Python. [`Weighted.LM.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/WeightedPortTest/versions/1.1/topics/Weighted.LM.test) from the `WeightedPortTest` package can do the Li-Mak test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Residuals vs Standardised Residuals. Residuals are the differences between your observed values and the values predicted by your model.
  Standardised Residuals in the context of GARCH models are the residuals divided by the conditional volatility (the square root of the conditional variance predicted by the GARCH model). The diagnostic tests below require standardised residuals.
- Apply the Ljung-Box test or Breusch-Godfrey test to the standardised residuals in order to detect autocorrelation.   Given the substantial number of observations (1039), it is feasible to examine a considerable number of lags, such as 20 or 30 lags.   However, in the case of GARCH models, it is often more pertinent to concentrate on the initial few lags, typically up to 10.
- Assess the presence of ARCH effects by using the Li-Mak test on standardised residuals. This test checks for the presence of autocorrelation in their squared values. Rejection of the null hypothesis (of no autocorrelation in squares) indicates that your GARCH model did not capture all ARCH patterns.
- For Goodness of Fit, you can inspect a QQ plot to assess whether the standardised residuals are plausibly t-distributed. You can also look at the overall goodness of fit for your model, which can include evaluating the AIC (Akaike Information Criterion) or BIC (Bayesian Information Criterion), especially if you are comparing multiple models. If you have alternative models, compare them using AIC, BIC, or likelihood ratio tests to see which model fits the data better.
- Assess the model's performance both in-sample and out-of-sample. Out-of-sample forecasting performance is crucial for understanding the model's practical applicability.
- Lastly, don't forget the power of visual inspection: plot the standardised residuals and their squared values to visually inspect for any patterns or anomalies.

Comment: *Assess the presence of ARCH effects by employing Engle's ARCH test on the squared standardised residuals.* This will not work. ARCH-LM works on raw data or residuals from a model that assumes constant conditional variance but not on standardized residuals from GARCH. Li-Mak test should be used instead. Also, what is the difference between bullet points 3 and 4 and the last one? You repeat yourself 3 times...

Comment: *For Goodness of Fit, you can inspect a QQ plot to assess whether the residuals are plausibly t-distributed.* Here we need standardized residuals.

Comment: @RichardHardy Doh !!!!!  Thanks for you comments, which are always appreciated. I was rather hasty in posting this originally. I've now made changes as per your comments.

Comment: *Some diagnostic checks on GARCH models require the raw residuals and some require standardised ones.* What checks would require raw residuals?

Comment: @RichardHardy none I suppose ! Answer updated. Thanks again :)